# Augmented battery make the BIOS block

Tags: laptop, boot, bios, battery

I've bought a new [battery](http://www.ebay.it/itm/270781776518?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649#ht_2514wt_1139) for my notebook, an old AMILO Li 2727, but when it is plugged in and I try to turn on the laptop, the BIOS blocks. If I remove it and restart the computer,
it works properly, even if I plug the battery after the end of the BIOS check.

I think is some control on the battery that fails and make the BIOS loop on the check, in fact when it is blocked, pressing F2/ESC/F12 make the string at the bottom of the screen change, writing "Entering into BIOS setup", but it will remain blocked (even the ctrl+alt+canc to reboot works).

Have you any solution for this problem?
Unfortunately the BIOS' features are not so numerous, and there isn't any options on the power pane (furthermore there isn't any power pane!)
I thought at a custom mod of the BIOS firmware, but I'm not so practice at flashing BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reset BIOS.Open your computer cabinet and remove your BIOS battery and let it be for some time and then again plug it.It should reset your BIOS.Try inserting new BIOS battery.